# WordPress: disable not found notification when latest posts set as front page

Tags: wordpress

I want my WordPress's front page to display some widgets only. It contains no posts and probably will never do.

But when I when I disable any static page as front page and posts page "your latest posts" automatically selects and as the site contains no posts at all a big annoying message NOT FOUND appears along with a search form.

I want to disable both message and and the search form so that the front page will be free of anything apart from widgets.

Is it possible?

Any strings to functions.php would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a crutch that can help in some cases, give it a try.

It is not disabling the message but hides it from page.

Insert the following strings into your template's css. This particular code is for WP's default Twenty Sixteen theme.

```
body.home section.no-results,
body.home section.not-found {
    display: none;
}
```

You may use another theme, in this case just look for the tag and its class that any annoying message is wrapped into and replace ***section.no-results*** and ***section.not-found*** with this tag and its class. But preserve ***body.home***, this will make you sure you are disabling this part only on the home page of your WP site.

Don't forget to make yourself sure this will not hide anything besides your problem.